# Use (Billy Meltdown) NSDate-helper methods to convert Unix timestamp and display?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, helper, unix-timestamp

I would like to convert a Unix timestamp e.g 1315401371 stored as a NSString into a date format of 23:00 12 October 2011.

There are a number of similar questions being ask in relation to this however I wish to use [billymeltdown / nsdate-helper methods](http://github.com/billymeltdown/nsdate-helper/wiki)

I have imported the 2 files (.h and .m) into my project, but have not manage to get further than that.
There is documentation, which I have read, however I am still very new to objective C and do not understand how I actual use the libraries.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSTimeInterval timestamp = 1315401371;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm dd MMMM yyyy"]; // use one d for 7 October instead of 07 October 

// For english month names
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
[usLocale release];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: I still want to use the NS-Date Helper Methods. But that will do for now. Thanks Stam.